# border-box isn't working as expected

Tags: html, css, border-box, box-sizing

I have two parent elements, and 3 children inside. (`#grandParent>#parent>#children*3`) `grandParent` has a set height and width, and `parent` has padding applied. All elements have `box-sizing: border-box`.

With `border-box` applied, the padding should make the `children` smaller, but instead, it pushed it down, and retains its size. Why doesn't the `children` become smaller when the padding is applied?

#### JSFiddle

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#grandParent {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
}
#parent {
  padding: 30px 5px;
}
.children {
  background: black;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
#reference {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grandParent">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="reference"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) on *an* element means you include `padding` and `border` into the width calculation of *that* element.

You only have `padding` applied on the `parent` and so it takes effect only there.

The `width` or `height` of `parent` is *auto* (default as its not specified). So try setting a `height` for instance, or adding `height: inherit` - you can see that the `padding` for `parent` is reduced on inspecting the element.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#grandParent {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
}
#parent {
  padding: 30px 5px;
  height: inherit;

}
.children {
  background: black;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
#reference {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grandParent">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="reference"></div>
```

Comment: you could set `height` and `width` on the `parent` and adjust its `padding`... want me to demo it?

Comment: Tried it. Still didn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/ryt72cvz/1/ Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/fb583ep4/ or even this: https://jsfiddle.net/u33661a3/