# How to adjust the spacing between input text and input submit

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an autocomplete form, but I seem to have some issues with the padding between the text and submit form.  I cannot seem to adjust the spacing between the text and submit items, which I need because when I increase the size of the text field, it overwrites the submit button. I believe I've tried all types of padding but they do nothing.  Can someone give me a clue please?

```css
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

input[type=text] {
  border-color: #808080;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you can increase the value of `margin-left` in `input[type=submit] {}`

Comment: @Thanthu Thanks, this worked.  Maybe a more suitable question would be hot to adjust the submit button based on the ending of the text field.  Is that possible?

Comment: You can add margin to the element where you want to add space to end. In your case add  `margin-right: 5px;` to `input[type=text]{}` is that what you meant. I've posted the comment as answer

Answer (score 1):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to your `input[type=text]` - the default *content-box* setting means that *when you add `padding` to an element it increases its dimensions*.

See demo below:

```css
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

input[type=text] {
  border-color: #808080;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* added */
}

input[type=submit] {
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You can see more examples here:

- [Add border to div increase div width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129811/add-border-to-div-increase-div-width/39130170#39130170)
- [border-box isn't working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604549/border-box-isnt-working-as-expected/41604754#41604754)

Comment: Did as you suggested, and when I increase the size of the text to 120% it still overwrites the submit button

Comment: why do you want to increase to greater that 100%? you have a fixed width set for the parent element

Comment: I want the ability to adjust things as needed, so wanted to know how.

Comment: see when you say 120% width, it is 120% of its parent's width and therefore *overflows* the parent `div.autocomplete` :) the issue with your code was you were saying `width: 100%` and the `padding` along with it was adding to this 100% width...

Comment: I hear you.  So in my example does that mean that the fields make up the 300px of the parent automatically and I shouldn't play with that?

Comment: yeah if you have `width: 100%` for the `input` then it occupies 100% of the width of `div.autocomplete` which is 300px... then all need to get the *space between* `div.autocomplete` and `input[type=submit]` is margin - you already have `margin-left` on `input[type=submit]`

Comment: even if you remove that `margin-left: 5px`, there is a *small gap* that is *natural* to *inline elements*...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `&nbsp;` between your input text and submit button?

```css
.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

input[type=text] {
  border-color: #808080;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php"> 
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;"> 
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">   
    </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the value of `margin-left` in `input[type=submit] {}` like shown below:

```
input[type=submit] {
  margin-left: 10px; /* increased value */
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: #fff;
}
```

or add margin right to the previous element like shown below:

```
input[type=text] {
  border-color: #808080;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px; /* add margin right */
}
```